# Sort the two date columns individually and cumulative effect?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two date columns and two size columns (one size column related to one date column) like you can see in the Following table. Now I want the two arrays where in the first array it will be sort by Collected and show the cumulative effect of CollectedSize and same with Staged and StagedSize.

Required:

Collected array   |
1/1/2016   |    1
11/1/2016  |    4
12/1/2016  |    6
30/1/2016  |    11

Staged array   |
13/1/2016   |   3
14/1/2016  |    7
18/1/2016  |    13
16/1/2016  |    20

### Table:

### | Collected  | CollectedSize  | Staged   |    StagedSize           |

### | 11/1/2016   |  3    |   14/1/2016   |   4

### | 12/1/2016   |  2    |   13/1/2016   |   3

### | 30/1/2016  |  5    |    18/1/2016   |   7

### | 01/1/2016  |  1    |    16/1/2016   |   6

Currently using the following code:

```
public class ProductionDataOverTimeVM
{
    public ProductionDataOverTimeVM()
    {
        Collected = new List<TimeChartXAxis>();
        Staged = new List<TimeChartXAxis>();
    }
    public List<TimeChartXAxis> Collected { get; set; }
    public List<TimeChartXAxis> Staged { get; set; }
}
public class TimeChartXAxis
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
}

var queryResults = context.Datasets.ToList();
ProductionDataOverTimeVM obj = new ProductionDataOverTimeVM();
long? collectedBytes = 0;
long? Staged = 0;
foreach (var dataset in queryResults.OrderBy(d => d.Collected))
{
    if (dataset.Collected != null)
    {
        collectedBytes = collectedBytes + dataset.CollectedSize;
        obj.Collected.Add(new TimeChartXAxis
        {
            x = dataset.Collected != null ? BasicHelpers.FromUTCDate(dataset.Collected, parms.Offset).Value.ToString("dd/M/yyyy") : null,
            y = BasicHelpers.FormatBytesToSpecificFormat(collectedBytes, format, false)
        });
    }
}
foreach (var dataset in queryResults.OrderBy(d => d.Staged))
{
    if (dataset.Staged != null)
    {
        Staged = Staged + dataset.StagedSize;
        obj.Staged.Add(new TimeChartXAxis
        {
            x = dataset.Staged != null ? BasicHelpers.FromUTCDate(dataset.Staged, parms.Offset).Value.ToString("dd/M/yyyy") : null,
            y = BasicHelpers.FormatBytesToSpecificFormat(Staged, format, false)
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

What will be the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var arrayofOrderByString = new []{"Collected","Staged"}

foreach(var key in arrayofOrderByString){
var y=0;
SortList<Datasets>(queryResults, key, SortDirection.Descending);
queryResults.foreach(s =>{
y=s.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(s, null);
obj.Collected.Add(new ProductionDataOverTimeVM{
x =BasicHelpers.FromUTCDate(s.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(s, null), parms.Offset).Value.ToString("dd/M/yyyy"),
y=collectedBytes
})
})
}

public void SortList<T>(List<T> list, string columnName, SortDirection direction)
{
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(columnName);
    var multiplier = direction == SortDirection.Descending ? -1 : 1;
    list.Sort((t1, t2) => {
        var col1 = property.GetValue(t1);
        var col2 = property.GetValue(t2);
        return multiplier * Comparer<object>.Default.Compare(col1, col2);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @jitender Thanks for the reply... Buddy can we minimize the loops here. In my questions i am showing only two but i have 10 number of coumns and we are applying 10 loops in a single method. Like in your answer you are also applying two loops. I mainly wants to minimize loops if possible.

Comment: @Manjit then you should modify your question .you should put the above comment in your question

Comment: @Manjit updated the ans she if it works.This is just an idea you can modify accordingly

Comment: .foreach(s => after SortList method call giving exception.There is no foreach availe after .(dot) after method call. :(

Comment: @Manjit i just update the answer as i already said this is just an idea you will need to modify accordingly